# When was the last face to face meeting between Iran government and USA government?

Tags: united-states, international, iran

While we know there is no official political relationship between Iran and USA, I want to know about the last one. I do not know about unofficial meetings or phone calls which may happen.

Comment: How do you define "government"? I'm pretty sure some US soldiers came face to face with some militants working for Iranian Government in Iraq.

Comment: The political agents of USA who have an official permission to talk with the other governments according to the defined policies.

Comment: You mean bilateral meetings as opposed to meetings in the United Nations or other such organizations?

Comment: No, It is not about meetings which happen in the UN.

Comment: It's always also a good idea to do a bit of research oneself and presenting it in question, especially for questions that lend themselves to googling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were regular meetings between the US and Iran governments up to the 1979 [Iranian Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_Revolution).

There was also contact between the US and Iran during the [Iran-Contra affair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran-Contra_Affair), but I don't know if you would consider that 'official'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there were meetings much later than that, duiring Iraq war. It may not have been advertized/acknowledged, but someone most likely talked.

Comment: I would not be surprised if there were more recent ones. I someone has evidence of them, I'll be happy to upvote their answer.

Comment: I would be very surprised if someone was willing to exachange 10 rep points on stack exchange for 10 years in jail :)

Comment: @DVK Do not scare my audiences! :))

Answer (score 4):

As a consequence of the [hostage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93United_States_relations#The_hostage_crisis),

> On April 7, 1980, Carter severed diplomatic relations between Iran and the United States and they have been frozen ever since.

US don't have an embassy in Iran, and Iran has no embassy in the US. Heads of states of both sides have never met in the last 40 years.

However, especially during the Obama administration and after Rohani's election, diplomatic talks have been staged and lead to the Iran Nuclear Deal. The highest level of these encouters included ministers of Foreign affairs, hence a governmental level.

You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_nuclear_deal_framework#/media/File:Negotiations_about_Iranian_Nuclear_Program_-_the_Ministers_of_Foreign_Affairs_and_Other_Officials_of_the_P5%2B1_and_Ministers_of_Foreign_Affairs_of_Iran_and_EU_in_Lausanne.jpg) an official meeting between ministers of Foreign affairs  Mohammad Javad Zarif (Iran) and John Kerry (USA), held in Lausanne, 2015, and leading to the Joint Comprehensive Plan of Action, or Iran Nuclear [Deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action).

Answer (score 0):

Befor Iranian Revolution, already mentionined in the answer by DJClayworth, Iran was one of the main US allies in the region as can be read in this wikipedia article about [Iran–United States relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93United_States_relations). If it´s only about face to face meeting, then the las such meeting seems to be 1977. I am tallking about The Iranian Shah, Mohammad Reza Pahlavi meeting with Alfred Atherton, William H. Sullivan, Cyrus Vance, President Jimmy Carter, and Zbigniew Brzezinski. To be more precise the meeting took place December 31, 1977 where Carter made his controversal [New Year's Eve 1978 toast to the Shah](https://www.bunkhistory.org/resources/3430). After that and untill the begin of the Iranian Revolution there were still contacts betwee Iranian and US officials, but I have no information if it were face to face meetings. Since the revolution started just a few days after that meeting 7 January 1978, it´s wery unlikely that any face to face meetings took place after that.

While 1977 was the last meeting where both Iran and USA were allies, the next and at the moment last meeting between the representants of the two governments took place 2015. The meeting was 14 January 2015 in Geneva during the negotiations about Iran nucler deal as can be read in [this BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-30805655).

Kerry said that he met with Zarif also after that meeting, but at that time he was not representing the US government any more.

Comment: The accepted answer suggests that there are meetings up until 1979 which is after your meeting, can you please provide evidence directly in your answer and not a link to another site that shows 1977 is the last meeting?

Comment: @Joe W The question was about face to face meeting and there is no information about any other meeting which took place after the one mentioned.

Comment: Can you provide some information in your answer that isn't just link for someone to read? An answer that is given over 9 years after the accepted answer should provide better explanation of why the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: @Joe W I have not said that the acepted answer is wrong, it´s just a bit incorect as the revolution in Iran has started jus a few days after the mentioned meeting.

Comment: During Obama presidency, Foreign Ministers of  Iran and US(Zarif/Kerry) had meetings many times. They are members of government.

Comment: @TMFG Shure, then you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @convert it's not worth for a 9 years old question.

Comment: @Joe W Which information is mising in my answer, willing to fix it.

Comment: I am not seeing anything to show that the last meeting was in 1977 instead of 1979 as the accepted answer shows.

Comment: @Joe W As mentioned in my answer the meeting took place in the last day of 1977 and just about a week after that the revolution began, so no good conditions for face to face meetings.

Comment: @TMFG Hope then you don´t mind, that I added it to my answer.